# How to setText 10 times in a TextView? more precisely how to print a multiplication from 1 to 10 in a single TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

here is the multiplication code:

```
for (i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
{
tvRes.setText("\n"+Number + "*" + i + "=" + (Number * i)+"\n");
}
```

and here is the xml Layout code for TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
```

Comment: Use string builder . Append the text you want to display and set it in the textview

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number is 2

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i =1;i<=10;i++){
        builder.append("\n"+2 + "*" + i + "=" + (2 * i)+"\n");
    }

  String textToPrint = builder.toString();
  tvRes.setText(textToPrint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will set new value for the `TextView` on each iteration of the `for-loop`. So you can either build the string first in the `for-loop` and then set the generated string using `tvRes.setText`. Alternatively you can append the current value of `tvRex.getText().toString()` on each iteration.

```
int Number = 1; //I am assuming because you did not show where you initialize it
String generatedString = "";
for (i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
{
  generatedString += ""+Number+"*"+i+"=" + (Number * i)+"\n");
}
  tvRes.setText(generatedString);
```

Give it a try and let me know if this helps.